# Android Project with Eclipse - HTML - WebSources

Tags: java, android, html, eclipse

I am creating an Android project with eclipse. My main on create class refers ton an HTML file so I can program my application within HTML (where I am most fluent) using this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView); 
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

}
```

This works just fine but when I work within my .html file I cannot fetch a file from the internet. For example this line:

```
<img src="http://www.johndoe.gr/newpicks.jpg"
```

It does not return the picture I want. What do I have to do to be able to fetch data from the web into my application?

ps. the picture link I added is random and does not refer to a real picture in the Question. I use a real link on my code and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Symeon - Have to Provided the Internet Permission in Manifest File.

And to use HTML i will suggest Please use Phonegap.. import CoroDova.jar and required Permissions for phonegap.. than when u run the HTML through Phonegap on Android i will run with ease and Even u will be able to use jquery mobile and javascripts and all

Comment: 1 st of all thank you very much for your response. I added this :

Comment: android.permission.INTERNET on the manifest file but still I cant get the result ...